# How can I set my laptop to remember my multiple display configuration?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have a notebook display and vga connected display to expand my desktopview.

Virtual desktops on linux are very well and easy to switch, but I need at least two displays.

I already tested randr but there are some problems when I take my notebook elswere.

The settings are not stored and I need to set up every time new. Am I doing something wrong?

This is little bit easier in windows.

Is there some application for ubuntu too?

Comment: Did you use the Monitors configuration dialog from System -> Preferences to set this with xrandr?  As far as I know it *should* remember previous settings, if not I suggest you file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings are stored in your xorg.conf file. I'm guessing you have an intel chip (you say netbook). Look [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEYQFjAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntu.com%2FX%2FConfig&ei=V1_cTJnmCsKB8gaYrdimCQ&usg=AFQjCNG5qupAHPXI1uAvie5iK3VYQS5bzQ&sig2=N9DzmFtFpAIQSwN4joJ61A) for some good information on making that permanent (it's easier with ati/nvidia, since it's mostly driver specific.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.
I Added this line in /etc/gdm/init/default
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --auto --output VGA-1 --auto --left-of LVDS-1
before this line
/sbin/initctl -q emit login-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm
Now it starts every time I login.
I also added some application starters to gnome pannel
For off the second monitor xrandr --output VGA-1 --off 
and to start it xrandr --output LVDS-1 --auto --output VGA-1 --auto --left-of LVDS-1

Comment: For info: this works only with non proprietary drivers on my lenovo 3000 N200 nvidia. but it works great.